# Sistema de votacion en Microsoft Access

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access, microsoft-office

Buenos días, solo necesito en que me ayuden con un código.

Necesito hacer un sistema de votación, ya tengo la tabla lista pero mi código no hace lo que le pidó.

Son dos preguntas:

A) Como valido correctamente que el usuario haya chequeado un checkbox?
B) Como hago para que sume on voto al votante en cuestion?

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

-Código:

```
 Private Sub Comando25_Click()
 Check1 As Boolean
 Check2 As Boolean
 Check3 As Boolean
 Check4 As Boolean

 If Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3 = True & Me.Check4 = True 
 Then
 MsgBox "No puedes seleccionar los cuatro, solo puedes seleccionar uno"
 DoCmd.Close
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
 End If

 If Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3 = True Then
 MsgBox "No puedes seleccionar tres, solo puedes seleccionar uno"
 DoCmd.Close
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
 End If

 If Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True Then
 MsgBox "No puedes seleccionar dos, solo puedes seleccionar uno"
 DoCmd.Close
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
 End If

 If Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3 = True Then
 MsgBox "No puedes seleccionar dos, solo puedes seleccionar uno"
 DoCmd.Close
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
 End If

  If Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check3 = True Then
MsgBox "No puedes seleccionar dos, solo puedes seleccionar uno"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If
End Sub
```

Así luce el formulario:
[image: Formulario]

Asi luce la tabla: (Votos es una variable numero por su puesto)
[image: Tabla]

Espero su respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Intentaste armar una tabla para registrar los votos en la que haya sólo dos columnas: el Id y la respuesta en base a una lista de búsqueda que podrías ubicar justo en medio de las 4 caras como un subformulario de tu formulario)?

Y en el que sólo puedas elegir 1 de los 4 que están listados, eso evitaría todos los límites que intentas ponerle. 
La otra es que sólo pueda poner un número el que más le guste entre 1 y 4, nada impide que se imprima su voto con todos los datos del candidato, sea para que vaya a la urna o sea conservado por él mismo.

Lo ideal sería una opción múltiple si/No que hasta donde sé sólo lo podrías hacer con Visual. Pero de eso me niego a saber